# Sum Conversion Rate and Then Group By Age

Tags: python, group-by, sum, pandas-groupby

I need to sum and group the conversion rate by age. The code below is from the book Hands-on Data Science for Marketing by Yoon Hyup Hwang.

The book provides the following code but it does not work:

```
conversions_by_age = df.groupby(by='age')
['conversion'].sum() / df.groupby(by='age')
['conversion'].count() * 100
```

The expected output would show:

Age column: 17   Conversion column: 40.0000
Age column: 18   Conversion column: 42.857143

and so on.

Here's the error I receive when I run the code from the book (line 2 is the issue per python):

```
  1 conversions_by_age = df.groupby(by='age')
  2 ['conversion'].sum() / df.groupby(by='age')
  3 ['conversion'].count() * 100
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'

```
const.price.idx  cons.conf.idx  euribor3m  nr.employed  y   conversion
93.994           -36.4          4.857      5191.0       no  0
93.994           -36.4          4.857      5191.0       no  0
93.994           -36.4          4.857      5191.0       no  0
93.994           -36.4          4.857      5191.0       no  0
93.994           -36.4          4.857      5191.0       no  0
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory `"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'`

In this line

```
['conversion'].sum()
```

`['conversion']` is list and you are accessing `sum` method of `list` and python list do not have any method name `sum`.

I think you should do

```
df['conversion'].sum() instead of ['conversion'].sum()
```

because `df` is a `DataFrame` which exposes `sum` method.

Comment: Hi Arpit Svt, 
I tried that and received this error (maybe it is the division sign?): TypeError: Could not operate 4640 with block values unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @deity what is the value of df?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Rakim/Desktop/New folder/bank-additional/bank-additional-full.csv")

Comment: Thanks for your help Arpit Svt. I figured it out: This is the correct code: conversions_by_age = df.groupby(
    by='age'
)['conversion'].sum() / df.groupby(
    by='age'
)['conversion'].count() * 100.0          pd.DataFrame(conversions_by_contacts)